# Find E(X^3) given X has the distribution Exp(2)

Tags: probability, statistics

Find $E(X^3)$ given $X$ is in $Exp(2)$

My idea is that we can use $f_X(x)=2e^{-2x}$ and integrate $\int_{0}^{a}x^3f_X(x)dx$. But from here I don't know where to go.

Comment: 3 integration by part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an exponential distribution $f(x|\lambda)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$, moments can be computed according to (source [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Mean,_variance,_moments_and_median))
$$\mathbb{E}\left ( X^n \right )=\frac{n!}{\lambda^n}$$

You can compute this equation by recurrence and integration by part
$\mathbb{E}\left ( X^n \right )=\frac{n}{\lambda}\mathbb{E}\left ( X^{n-1} \right )$. In your particular application, $\mathbb{E}\left ( X^3|\lambda=2 \right )=\frac{3!}{2^3}=\frac{3}{4}$

Answer (score 0):

Let $X\sim E(\lambda)$, i.e., $f_X(x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$. The $n^{th}$ moment of $X$ would be:

$E\{X^n\} = \int\limits_{0}^{+\infty} x^n e^{-\lambda x} \lambda dx$

Let $u=\lambda x$, then the integration becomes:

$E\{X^n\} = \int\limits_{0}^{+\infty} \dfrac{u^n}{\lambda^n} e^{-u} du
= \dfrac{1}{\lambda^n} \int\limits_{0}^{+\infty} u^n e^{-u} du
= \dfrac{1}{\lambda^n} \Gamma(n+1) = \dfrac{n!}{\lambda^n}$

where $\Gamma()$ is the gamma function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function